# ItemSelected event not firing on ListView that's being populated using ListView Adapter - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin.android, listadapter

To expand on the title:

- I am using an `Adapter` in xamarin for Android to populate a `ListView`.
- I'm also using a `RecyclerView` which is a row to populate the `ListView`, each row of which contains an 
  `Imageview` and 2x `Textview`.
- When I click anywhere on a row, I need the `ItemSelected` event to fire within the Activity itself, so that I may do something similar to

  ```
  mListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
  {
     System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("LISTVIEW CLICKED AT  : " + e.Position);      
     //Once I know the row position, I can do the rest.
  };
  ```
- Answers i've utilised:

  [Not able to fire the ListVIew Item click event when there is UI Control like Button in xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37154171/not-able-to-fire-the-listview-item-click-event-when-there-is-ui-control-like-but) - recommends setting:

  ```
  "Focusable = false" //on any element in the row
  ```

  While in this answer [Unable to get listView.ItemClick to be called in MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443364/unable-to-get-listview-itemclick-to-be-called-in-monodroid), a short quote from the answer reveals that

> "the problem was my ImageButton in the ListView. It
>   was stealing the focus and consuming the touch events."

LilMoke's solution was to set the following properties of each element in the row he wishes to fire the `ItemSelected` event upon:

```
imageButton.Focusable = false;
imageButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
imageButton.Clickable = true;

imageButton.Click += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("ImageButton {0} clicked", position);
```

Seems fine, which led to a later suggestion to:

Put

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

in your LinearLayout , assuming your RecycleView's root element is a LinearLayout

because Android doesn't allow any items to be focusable in `ListView`. A more concise version of preventing row items obtaining focus. The problem is after implementing this, I still can't get the `ItemSelected` event to fire.

What i've tried as a messy workaround:

1)
I have tried grabbing and setting the `Focusable` and `Clickable` properties from each element from within the `RecyclerView` template's declaration, but this is messy and does not allow me access to the StartActivity function which is part of any class that inherits directly from Activity. 
Because this is an adapter, it inherits from BaseAdapter<> instead.

Previous questions of mine have been scorned but after reading through  [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180692/why-do-i-receive-downvotes-when-i-am-genuinely-trying-to-learn/180698#180698), I am trying to change my wicked ways.

Here is the code relevant to what i've described and should better illustrate the situation:

row.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="#F1F1F1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPic"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_person"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="25"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3B5998"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="65">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:text="Contact Name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
            android:text="(555)-444-2222"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="65"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#000" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/xiconsmall"
        android:id="@+id/btnDeleteAlbum" />
</LinearLayout>
```

listContacts.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
            android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"
            android:clickable="true" />
        <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

ListContacts.cs

```
namespace MainMobileDevProject
{
    [Activity(Label = "Display row items", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/xs")]    
    //public class ListContacts: AppCompatActivity
    public class ListContacts : Activity
    {
        private ListView mListView;
        private BaseAdapter<Contact> mAdapter;
        private List<Contact> mContacts;
        private ImageView mSelectedPic;        
        private Button mBtnAddPics, button;
        public List<byte[]> imagesByteList = new List<byte[]>();
        public List<string> imagesTagsList = new List<string>();
        Bitmap myBitmap;


        private ImageView _imageView;

        public static class App
        {
            public static File _file;
            public static File _dir;
            public static Bitmap bitmap;
        }

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.listContacts);

            string text = Intent.GetStringExtra("MyData") ?? "Data not available";
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("DATA WE PASSED HERE IS : " + text);

            mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);
            mContacts = new List<Contact>();
            mBtnAddPics = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnAdd);

            //mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.pager_item, mContacts, action);
            mAdapter = new ContactListAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.row_contact, mContacts);




            //having an issue with my list adapter
            //none of my event items such as click or itemselected will fire
            //debug log aren't even firing, the proposed solution is to set each row's child elements to have a value of
            //false for "focusable", and a better solution again is to set the root of the row's layout to have 
            // an attribute of android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". this can be seen in row_contact.axml
            //the problem though is that now the row's contents can be accessed, but not from this module, but only in the adapter, which makes things messy of course, but I haven't been able to start a new activity
            //    due to my adapter(ContactListAdapter.cs) inheriting from the BaseAdapter class


            mListView.ItemClick += lv_ItemClick;

            void lv_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
            {
                //not firing
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("LISTVIEW CLICKED AT  : " + e.Position);
            }


                mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;
                //mListView.NotifyDataSetChanged();


            mListView.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("LISTVIEW CLICKED AT  : " + e.Position);
            };

            mListView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("LISTVIEW CLICKED AT  : " + e.Position);
            };

            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        private void MListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row id : " + e.Id);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row parent is : " + e.Parent);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row position : " + e.Position);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row view : " + e.View);
        }



        private void MBtnAddPics_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=someawsconstring.something.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com;Port=3307;database=ichangedthis;User Id=ichangedthis;Password=ichangedthis;charset=utf8");
            //List<string> imageslist = new List<string>();
            //List<byte[]> imageslist = new List<byte[]>();

            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("CONN OPEN");
                    //string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUserAlbumPhoto HAVING UserID = '" + Intent.GetStringExtra("UsersID") + "' AND AlbumID = '" + Intent.GetStringExtra("UsersID") +"'";                    
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUserAlbumPhoto HAVING UserID = '" + 1 + "' AND AlbumID = '" + 1 +"'";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("TRYING TO READ");
                    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dataReader.Read())
                    {                        
                        imagesByteList.Add(Convert.FromBase64String(dataReader.GetString(4)));
                        imagesTagsList.Add(dataReader.GetString(5));
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("image still as base64 string is : " + dataReader.GetString(1));
                        //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("image converted from base64 found is : " + Convert.FromBase64String(dataReader.GetString(1)));
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("image ID found is : " + imagesByteList[0]);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("image ID found is : " + imagesByteList[1]);
                }

            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("CONN CLOSED");
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("image ID count found is : " + imagesByteList.Count);
            }

            CountImagesList();
            if (imagesByteList.Count > 0) //just a test
            {
                CreateImgFromBytes(imagesByteList, imagesTagsList);
            }
        }

        private void CreateImgFromBytes(List<byte[]> imageslist, List<string> tags)
        {
            //foreach(byte[] ba in imageslist)
            for(int y=0;y<imagesByteList.Count;y++)
            {
                mContacts.Add(new Contact() { Name = tags[y], Image = imageslist[y] });
            }
            //mContacts.Add(new Contact() { Name = "abc", Number = "def", Image = imageslist[0] });
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("imageslist lentth is: " + imageslist.Count);
            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            //Decode with InJustDecodeBounds = true to check dimensions
            //Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data);
            //BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            //options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
            //BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);

            ////Calculate InSamplesize
            //options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, requestedWidth, requestedHeight);

            ////Decode bitmap with InSampleSize set
            //stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data); //Must read again
            //options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream, null, options);
            //return bitmap;
        }

        public void CountImagesList()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("imageslist lentth is: " + imagesByteList.Count);
        }

        private void PicSelected(ImageView selectedPic)
        {
            mSelectedPic = selectedPic;
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.SetType("image/*");
            intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
            this.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Selecte a Photo"), 0);
        }

        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            //if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            //{
            //    Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
            //    mSelectedPic.SetImageBitmap(DecodeBitmapFromStream(data.Data, 150, 150));
            //}

            Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);

            Uri contentUri = Uri.FromFile(App._file);
            mediaScanIntent.SetData(contentUri);
            SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

            // Display in ImageView. We will resize the bitmap to fit the display.
            // Loading the full sized image will consume to much memory
            // and cause the application to crash.

            int height = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
            int width = _imageView.Height;
            App.bitmap = App._file.Path.LoadAndResizeBitmap(width, height);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("APP . BITMAP IS :: " + App.bitmap);
            if (App.bitmap != null)
            {
                _imageView.SetImageBitmap(App.bitmap);
                myBitmap = App.bitmap;
                //App.bitmap = null;
            }

            // Dispose of the Java side bitmap.
            GC.Collect();
        }

        private void CreateDirectoryForPictures()
        {
            App._dir = new File(
                Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DirectoryPictures), "Base64Attempt");
            if (!App._dir.Exists())
            {
                App._dir.Mkdirs();
            }
        }

        private bool IsThereAnAppToTakePictures()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            IList<ResolveInfo> availableActivities =
                PackageManager.QueryIntentActivities(intent, PackageInfoFlags.MatchDefaultOnly);
            return availableActivities != null && availableActivities.Count > 0;
        }

        private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Uri.FromFile(App._file));
            StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

        private Bitmap DecodeBitmapFromStream(Android.Net.Uri data, int requestedWidth, int requestedHeight)
        {
            //Decode with InJustDecodeBounds = true to check dimensions
            System.IO.Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);

            //Calculate InSamplesize
            options.InSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize(options, requestedWidth, requestedHeight);

            //Decode bitmap with InSampleSize set
            stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data); //Must read again
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream, null, options);
            return bitmap;
        }

        private int CalculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options, int requestedWidth, int requestedHeight)
        {
            //Raw height and widht of image
            int height = options.OutHeight;
            int width = options.OutWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (height > requestedHeight || width > requestedWidth)
            {
                //the image is bigger than we want it to be
                int halfHeight = height / 2;
                int halfWidth = width / 2;

                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > requestedHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > requestedWidth)
                {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }

            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.actionbar_home, menu);
            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        }

        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                case Resource.Id.add:

                    CreateContactDialog dialog = new CreateContactDialog();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

                    //Subscribe to event
                    dialog.OnCreateContact += dialog_OnCreateContact;
                    dialog.Show(transaction, "create contact");
                    return true;

                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }

        void dialog_OnCreateContact(object sender, CreateContactEventArgs e)
        {
            mContacts.Add(new Contact() { Name = e.Name, Number = e.Number });
            mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /*
    public static class BitmapHelpers
    {
        public static Bitmap LoadAndResizeBitmap(this string fileName, int width, int height)
        {
            // First we get the the dimensions of the file on disk
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
            BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);

            // Next we calculate the ratio that we need to resize the image by
            // in order to fit the requested dimensions.
            int outHeight = options.OutHeight;
            int outWidth = options.OutWidth;
            int inSampleSize = 1;

            if (outHeight > height || outWidth > width)
            {
                inSampleSize = outWidth > outHeight
                                   ? outHeight / height
                                   : outWidth / width;
            }

            // Now we will load the image and have BitmapFactory resize it for us.
            options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
            options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileName, options);

            return resizedBitmap;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

ContactListAdapter.cs

```
namespace MainMobileDevProject
{
    class ContactListAdapter : BaseAdapter<Contact>
    {
        private Context mContext;
        private int mLayout;
        private List<Contact> mContacts;
        private Action<ImageView> mActionPicSelected;

        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Contact> contacts, Action<ImageView> picSelected)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mLayout = layout;
            mContacts = contacts;
            mActionPicSelected = picSelected;
        }

        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Contact> contacts)
        {
            mContext = context;
            mLayout = layout;
            mContacts = contacts;

        }

        public override Contact this[int position]
        {
            get { return mContacts[position]; }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return mContacts.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;
            //row.notif
            if (row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(mLayout, parent, false);
            }

            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtName).Text = mContacts[position].Name;
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtNumber).Text = mContacts[position].Number;

            ImageView pic = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPic);
            row.Clickable = true;

            if (mContacts[position].Image != null)
            {
                pic.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(mContacts[position].Image, 0, mContacts[position].Image.Length));
            }

            if (mContacts[position].Image == null)
            {
                //here we should replace mcontacts[position] with imageslist[position], then it'll at least pull
                //the 2 byte[] images we have
                //pic.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(mContacts[position].Image, 0, mContacts[position].Image.Length));
                //pic.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(mContacts[position].Image, 0, mContacts[position].Image.Length));
            }
```

This is the messy workaround I had described above, can't continue using it

```
            //var imageButton = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPic);
            //imageButton.Focusable = false;
            //imageButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            //imageButton.Clickable = true;

            var removeButton = row.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.btnDeleteAlbum);
            removeButton.Focusable = false;
            removeButton.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
            removeButton.Clickable = true;

            //imageButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
            //{
            //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row id :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ");
            //    Console.WriteLine("ImageButton {0} clicked", position);

            //};

            removeButton.Click += (sender, args) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("myBitmap row id :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ");
                Console.WriteLine("RemoveButton {0} clicked", position);

            };



            //pic.Click -= pic_Click;
            pic.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Port=3307;database=ofsligodb;User Id=ofoley1;Password=pinecone;charset=utf8");

                try
                {
                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        con.Open();
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CONNECTION OPEN*****: ");



                        MySqlCommand Readcmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblUserAlbumPhoto WHERE UserID = '" + 1 + "' AND " +
                            "AlbumID = '" + 1 + "' and ID = '" + position + "'");


                        Readcmd.Connection = con;
                        Readcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DELETE SHOULD HAVE HAPPENED*****: ");


                    }

                }

                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    //mTxtImgChoiceInfo.Text = ex.ToString();
                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CONN CLOSED*****: ");
                }
            };

            return row;
        }



        void pic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Picture has been clicked
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("YOU CLICKED ME AND THE ROW INDEX WAS : " + e.position);

        }
    }
}
```

- Just to clarify, some relevant code is included that shows this `Listview` being populated after a button click which loads images from a MySql database.
- There is some code shown for resizing the loaded bitmaps into a thumbnail, no problems there either.
  All database-related and image re-sizing code works just fine, but I felt was important to include anyhow for other's understanding. If it's the case that it's obstructing people from grasping the overall project, please advise and i'll remove.

Any ambiguities/confusion please let me know.
If a duplicate please be kind enough to explain why, thank you.

Comment: Try to comment the code `row.Clickable = true;`, after commenting it, your code works fine by my side.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need add OnClick on every `View row` in your adapter.